# Firebase Authentication using Google fails below Android Lollipop

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have an app which stores data on Firebase and needs authentication (google) for the same. The login seems to work on other devices, however when I try to login from Nexus 7 it simply fails.

After some research I found some suggestions and I tried updating firebase app settings, adding new SHA and downloading the latest google-services.json but nothing seems to work.
Below is the log.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9001, result=0, data=null} to activity
{com.culminanttech.carmate/com.culminanttech.carmate.GoogleSignInActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.culminanttech.carmate.GoogleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInActivity.java:127)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at     com.culminanttech.carmate.GoogleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInActivity.java:127)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:** I tried [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) example also but I get the same crash.

**2nd EDIT:** After testing on some devices I realised that it seems to work on Lollipop and above only. Wonder what is the issue below lollipop. Does it have to do something with the play services?